# java 1.6 upgrade

Tags: java, jaxb, java-6, unmarshalling

We recently upgraded to jdk1.6. Result of which we had to get rid of all jaxb related jar from the project as jdk 1.6 has support for jaxb. Now when we are trying populate the jaxb object getting following error

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element
```

Although same xsd and xml combinations did worked before before with the jaxb jar. Do i need to update my xsd/xml?

Comment: This looks like a problem with validation: maybe it was disabled before and now it is enabled or schema definition has changed (no old XML does not pass anymore) or XSD that is used is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile xsd again. Remove xercesImpl.jar jaxb-api.jar and other from your classpath.

Comment: If the model was generated from an XML schema (the OP may have started from classes), then the model would only need to be regenerated if the schema changed.